# aws api gateway api key access

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed an AWS apigateway -> lambda integration.

The apigateway has one POST method which requires an api_key.

I have added that api key in my request headers under the `X-API-Key` key and the `x-api-key` and every time I still get a:

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I am running out of ideas, there are definitely no typos and the key is enabled as a `HEADER` source too.

Does anyone know what I might be missing in order to have the request authenticate properly?

I am invoking it like so:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://my-endpoint/resource' \
--header 'X-Api-Key: mykey'
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useful Checklist:

- Api key is created
- Api usage plan is created
- Api stage is created
- Api usage plan is associated with the api stage
- Api usage plan is associated with the api key
- Api key is sent in http header x-api-key

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped a lot, I had done all these steps accept associating the usage plan with the stage.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here to get this answer, an API needs to have a `usage plan` in order to validate the api-key.

This was failing because there was no usage plan.